# How can we recover unexpectedly deleted .zip files aws EC2 via putty?

Tags: amazon-web-services, putty

I have unexpectedly  deleted .zip files from AWS EC2 instance.

i don't have any CUI console .I'm only using putty to access directory on this instance.

Please guide me for this issue.

Comment: Be sure to provide key information such as which OS is running on the EC2 instance and whether or not you can get admin/root permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you can’t. The only way would be possible is if you have snapshots enabled that you could recover.

Answer (score 0):

If your EC2 storage is on EBS (Elastic Block Store) and you have snaphots of it, then you can retrieve it from there.

Since you only have access to the EC2 through ssh, [here is the command line info to see if you have any EBS snapshots](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-snapshots.html) using the `describe-snapshots` command of the AWS CLI